# How to get inputs accepted in this program?

Tags: c

I can't take inputs except string.
If I give inputs in code itself, program is working.
But when I try to take inputs, its not working.
How do I get it to accept given inputs?
For example, if s were "codebook", and from == 'o' and to == 'e', s would become "cedebeek".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 50
void replace(char *s, char from, char to)
{
  int i=0;
  while(s[i]!='\0')
   {
      if(s[i]==from)
       {
          s[i]=to;
       }
      i++;
   }
}
int main()
{
  char str[MAX];
  char from;
  char to;
  printf("Enter the string");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",&str[0]);

  printf("\nEnter the character to be replaced");
  scanf("%c",&from);

  printf("\nEnter the character to be replaced with");
  scanf("%c",&to);

  replace(str, from, to);
  printf("\nThe modified string is %s",str);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",&str[0]);` --> `scanf("%[^\n]",str);`, and `scanf("%c",&from);` --> `scanf(" %c",&from);`

Comment: Why do you have this scanf("%[^\n]s",&str[0]);

Comment: Why not just scanf("%s",&str[0]);

Comment: @physicist buffer overflow if they type too many characters. And `%s` stops at whitespace whereas `%[` does not.

Comment: @M.M  ahh ok I got it.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: scanf("%49[^\n]", str);
this is 49 characters and one for null terminator \0

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in the posted code. Since arrays decay to pointers to their first elements in most expressions, there is no need for the address operator `&` in the call to `scanf()`; also, the trailing `s` is not part of the scanset conversion specifier:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str);
```

As pointed out by [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877582/how-to-get-inputs-accepted-in-this-program/44877683#comment76733842_44877683) in the comments, it is not incorrect to use `&str[0]` here instead of `str`, but it is more idiomatic, and I personally find it more clear, to use the less cluttered `str`.

When `scanf()` returns, a newline character will be left in the input stream, so you should add a leading space in the next call to `scanf()` to skip over this `\n` character before reading the user input:

```
scanf(" %c",&from);
```

And this call to `scanf()` will also leave a `\n` character in the input stream, so again:

```
scanf(" %c",&to);
```

Note that you should really specify a maximum width to avoid buffer overflow when reading user input into a string; there is no easy way to do this with `MAX`, but you can do:

```
scanf("%49[^\n]", str);
```

You could further improve code and ensure that input is as expected by checking the values returned by the calls to `scanf()`.

Comment: IMO it's OK to write `&x[0]` instead of `x`, they are exactly equivalent and in some ways it's more readable (especially to people who don't understand arrays and pointers)

Comment: @M.M-- not sure that I agree with "it's more readable", but I take your point about the possibilty that learners may find this notation more clear.